# SonarQube hanging at Load project settings

Tags: sonarqube, freeze

I have a project that is hanging when it gets to "Load project settings"

```
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project_Sonar/workspace/target/sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1
[INFO] [12:35:43.126] Load global repositories
[INFO] [12:35:43.437] Load global repositories (done) | time=315ms
[INFO] [12:35:43.443] Server id: 20150416114227
[INFO] [12:35:43.446] User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
[INFO] [12:35:43.467] Install plugins
[INFO] [12:35:46.426] Install JDBC driver
[INFO] [12:35:46.443] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://192.16.16.116:3306/sonar02?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
[INFO] [12:35:49.494] Initializing Hibernate
[INFO] [12:35:53.844] Load project repositories
[INFO] [12:35:54.217] Load project repositories (done) | time=372ms
[INFO] [12:35:54.217] Load project settings
```

Any recommendations on troubleshooting would be appreciated.

The last line of access.log is

```
[16/Apr/2015:12:35:54 -0600] "GET /batch/project?key=products-project-aggregator&amp;preview=false HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "SonarQube Maven/3.2.2"
```

and nothing related in sonar.log